# how to polyfill through webpack to apply polyfill to an imported library?

Tags: javascript, webpack, polyfills

I'm using [redux-api-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-api-middleware) and after realizing I need to apply a polyfill for some browsers, I can't figure out how to have that polyfill affect redux-api-middleware.

I'm using webpack, to bundle my code. Using the whatwg-fetch polyfill here's the entry part of my webpack:
`entry: ['whatwg-fetch', APP_DIR + '/index.js']`

That works great if I use fetch in my own javascript code. However the API calls I'm doing with `redux-api-middleware` still don't seem to be happening (inspected in network, no API call is happening on unsupportive browsers). There is no error though, so I might be wrong that this is the issue, but my guess is that the polyfill is not applying to the imported library.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just follow the link https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/
I had tried it earlier referring it since I needed to used polyfill for Internet Explorer.

Comment: After much toil, I figured it out. It wasn't a webpack issue. basically the browser fetch accepts a GET with a body = {} whereas the polyfill will complain if it's anything but `null` for GET requests. I will write an answer and update the question for future seekers.